# Remember radio button selection in Django

Tags: django

Without using javascript, is there a better way to remember a user's radio button selection? I feel I have a pretty naive(?) way of doing it?

How can I re-write this to make it more DRY? `usersegment` parem gets returned on the same page upon submit.

```
{% if usersegment == "non-paying" %}
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="non-paying" checked="yes"/> Non-paying Users <br />
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="paying" /> Paying Users <br />
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="all" /> All Users<br />
{% endif %}

{% if usersegment == "paying" %}
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="non-paying" /> Non-paying Users <br />
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="paying" checked="yes"/> Paying Users <br />
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="all" /> All Users<br />
{% endif %}

{% if usersegment == "all" or not usersegment %}
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="non-paying" checked="yes"/> Non-paying Users <br />
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="paying" /> Paying Users <br />
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="all" checked="yes"/> All Users<br />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a model form? That would save the state of the form for you using the RadioSelect Widget

Comment: To be honest because I haven't read up on it yet. I guess it's time to open that chapter.

Comment: It's well worth it! We use them and pass them through a custom 'render to' to keep them nice and uniform from project to project. The designers love it as they can keep using all the old boilerplate CSS for forms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="non-paying" {% if usersegment == "non-paying" %}checked="checked"{% endif %}/> Non-paying Users <br />
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="paying" {% if usersegment == "paying" %}checked="checked"{% endif %}/> Paying Users <br />
<input type="radio" name="usersegment" value="all" {% if usersegment == "all" or not usersegment %}checked="checked"{% endif %}/> All Users<br />
```

Also, consider using [django forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs). Trivial problems like those are solved in a very elegant way there, you don't even need to think about it.

Comment: Right ok. I'm still learning Django and skipped that chapter.